# Why use "ref" in when passing objects (not structs)?

Tags: c#, .net

Which one is better in terms of memory?  I have always used snippet 2.. Is Snippet 1 better in anyway than snippet 2 (performance,memory) ?

```
Snippet 1
public void GetListOfString(ref List<string> x)
{
    x = new List<string>(){"Dave","John"};
}


Snippet 2
public List<string> GetListOfString()
{
 return new List<string>(){"Dave","John"};

}
```

Comment: With inlining both methods probably perform the same, memory and CPU wise.

Comment: There would no 'memory difference' as they both create a new object. Any speed difference, if any, wrt ref is also irrelevant. Use #2 and don't worry about such silliness in the sake 'performance'. The point of `ref` (or `out`) is primarily to allow the *binding* in the caller to be re-assigned.

Comment: Besides `List<T>` is anyway a class (reference type) and always passed to methods as reference, so your `ref` keyword doesn't make any difference as it wasn't there.

Comment: @AndriyHoren -- Please note that I have assigned a new object to x ... So if ref keyword was not used , the calling function will not have the changes reflected

Comment: Snippet 2 is much better, in term of readability, The other two factors are micro-optimizations that you won't need 99.9% of the time.

Comment: In your example, it would be more appropriate to use `out` rather than `ref` because anything that is passed in is ignored anyway.  It would be appropriate to use `ref` if you wanted to pass something in, use it in the method and potentially change it.  To have a `void` method with a single `out` parameter is bad practice.  Only use `out` parameters if you want to output multiple values that are peers or you are already returning something but want to output something else too, e.g. `TryParse` naturally returns a `bool` because it always succeeds or fails but sometimes outputs a value too.

Comment: The comment of @Pierre-LucPineault should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your first example should be using `out`, not `ref`:

```
public void GetListOfString(out List<string> x)
```

The method doesn't care what the incoming value is; it just overwrites whatever was there. Using `out` ensures that a) the caller is not required to initialize the variable before passing it, and b) the method itself *is* required to initialize the variable before returning (which will ensure against bugs).

If there is any performance difference at all (and I doubt you could measure one), I would expect the first example to be *slower*, because it has to pass a reference to a variable. Passing by-reference means there has to be a memory location involved where the method can modify the variable's value.  Returning a value is a highly optimized scenario, with the value often even stored in a register. And if the variable isn't passed by-reference, then the compiler may be able to enregister the caller's variable too, for an additional performance gain.

And of course, if data is kept in registers rather than being stored on the stack, that represents a (marginal, inconsequential, completely unimportant) reduction in memory footprint too.

But performance and memory footprint should not be your first concern anyway. The primary concern, and in 99.94% of all code the *only* concern, is what makes sense semantically and operationally. If the method has a need to modify a caller's variable, then pass by-reference, `ref` or `out` as appropriate to the scenario. If not, then pass by-value. Period.

Note that if just one variable of the caller needs to be modified, and the method does not otherwise have to return anything (i.e. would be `void`), then it is considered a much better practice to let the caller handle modifying the variable, and just return the new value for the variable (i.e. as in your second example).

If and when you come to a point in your code where for some reason, you just cannot achieve some *specific* and *measurable* performance or memory footprint goal, and you can *prove* that using passing by-reference will ensure that you will achieve that goal, then you can use performance as a motivation for passing by-reference. Otherwise, don't give it a second thought.

Answer (score 1):

Snippet 2 is much better in terms of readability and usability.

It is probably also slightly better in terms of performance and memory.

But this is just because the caller is forced to create a new list to even call snippet 1. You could argue that this overhead will be optimized away by the compiler, but don't rely on it.

If you had used `out` instead of `ref` for snippet 1, then I would say they are the same in terms of performance and memory.

I can sympathize with someone coming from a different programming language background thinking that snippet 1 would be better, but in C# reference types are returned by reference, not copied like they could be in some other languages.

Comment: _"the caller is forced to create a new list to even call snippet 1"_ -- that is not correct. The caller is forced to initialize the variable, but `null` is a perfectly legal value to initialize it to (and a `new` is not going to be optimized away, since constructors can have side-effects).

Comment: _"not copied like they could be in some other languages"_ -- other mainstream languages return references too. E.g. Java always does, except for primitives, and C++ does when returning pointers. The real difference in C++ is that whether the whole object or a pointer is returned depends not on the type, but on how the type is used (i.e. you decide between value and reference semantics on a per-variable and per-function basis, not on a per-type basis).

Comment: Excellent points. You are completely right. Regarding the second comment: I was indeed thinking of C++ when I wrote it - that a similar syntax in C++ could be taken to mean return by value. If I'm not mistaken I think that whether C++ actually does make a copy of the object depends on how the compiler does optimization. That is a bit interesting in itself, because it comes back around to your point about the compiler not optimizing away constructors, which it would have to do for the return value by no longer calling the copy constructor.